# Will a web server IP be blacklisted for sending SPAM via authenticated SMTP?

Tags: email

A hosting company a client is using blocks the sending of emails via SMTP, they say this is to protect the reputation of their server IP.

My question is, if I have a PHP web application which is sending spam emails via authenticated SMTP (Gmail), will the hosting companies server IP get a bad reputation, or will it (as I believe) be the SMTP servers IP address that would get a bad reputation?

Or will the server IP get a bad reputation with Gmail (the SMTP provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting companies have been tightening their policies where email is concerned.  For example, I have an app that allows my users to send email to their participants.  Yahoo will not let you send an email to their users if the server sending the email isn't a yahoo server and the from address is a yahoo address.  I am forced to use a No.Reply@MyDomain.com so that the from email address maps to the sending server.  GMail is just as tight but implements different rules, all in an effort to avoid Spam.  Whether or not your email is "authenticated" means nothing, that can be spoofed and often is in an effort to get around all the filters and rules.  I run my own email server and I am constantly adjusting my filters and rule to prevent Spam and I constantly monitor other email hosting companies to ensure that I do not get a spamming reputation.  One time that actually required a phone call to GMail support to get them to accept email from my server due to a policy change last year.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying, but in the case of this web application, it sends the email via Gmails SMTP service using a real email account/password. I understand the restrictions sending using PHP mails function, as the email is originating from the web server, but using SMTP the email is sent just as if it was sent from the email account holders email client.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the only way a IP can get a bad rep.  The receiving servers can tarnish the reputation of certain email address and IP's that support them.  I have on a couple of occasions had my IP end up on a public block list which required a phone call to one and several emails to them and the second one.  It's a constant battle and some companies are opting not to spend the resources to maintain their reputations and consequently don't aloow mass emails.